# PersistenceContext is not injected

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have a Java8/Spring4 webapp running on WildFly 10, and I want to use JPA 2.1.

I have created a persitence.xml file, and a dao class using a small snippet taken from the [jboss reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PersistenceContext):

```
@Stateful  // will use container managed transactions
public class UserDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "customerPU") // default type is PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION
  EntityManager em;

  public customer createCustomer(String name, String address) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(name, address);
    em.persist(customer);
}
```

Unfortunately, the entity manager is not injected as it should. I read [in a tutorial](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/README.html) that:

> The @PersistenceContext annotation can be used on any CDI bean, EJB,
>   Servlet, Servlet Listener, Servlet Filter, or JSF ManagedBean.

I thought that using the @Stateful annotation automatically made my dao class be a (ej)bean and thus the injecting would occur by the jboss container, but it doesn't happen and I get a `NullPointerException`when I call the `.persist` method. Why is that and can I fix it? I already tried using the `@Stateless` annotation instead and trying the PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED instead of the default TRANSACTIONAL one, but this doesn't seem to change anything. Please clearly describe if the solution to this problem requires additional libraries (spring, hibernate) or if it's just a matter of configuration (persistence.xml, standalone.xml...)

I see this in my logging and I'm not sure what it means:

> INFO  [] [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for
>   session bean named 'UserDao' in deployment unit 'deployment
>   "BasicWebapp.war"' are as follows:
>
> java:global/BasicWebapp/UserDao!com.company.project.data.UserDao
>     java:app/BasicWebapp/UserDao!com.company.project.data.UserDao
>     java:module/UserDao!com.company.project.data.UserDao
>     java:global/BasicWebapp/UserDao     java:app/BasicWebapp/UserDao
>     java:module/UserDao

I know that my datasource and persistence.xml have been configured correctly because I managed to get the injection work by putting the snippet above inside my `ServletContextListener` class (just as a small test, I know it doesn't make sense to be there). Just for reference, here is the concise persistence.xml file which uses mostly defaults provided by jboss:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="customerPU" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/customerdb</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.company.project.data.Customer</class>

    </persistence-unit> 

</persistence>
```

Comment: Have you setup logging? If no error are logged, try to increase the log level to debug or trace. It might give you hints on what gets injected and what not.

Comment: Hi Jan, I set logging to TRACE. There are no errors and everything gets instantiated. He finds the PU, the DAO and the persistenceContext annotation.  However, when it comes to injecting I only see this: PersistenceUnitService (phase 1 of 2) for 'service jboss.persistenceunit."BasicWebapp.war#CustomerPu".__FIRST_PHASE__'.  PU is ready for injector action.

Comment: I thiink the problem is that the UserDao class is not being created s a bean by my container. I simply do UserDao = new UserDao().

Comment: I that is true, it cannot work. Injection takes places when the container creates objects. Inject the UserDao into the class making the call to createCustomer().

Comment: @Jan how can I inject a class (without using spring)?

Comment: If you follow the example, take a look at the TestCase.
 final Context context = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p).getContext();
Movies movies = (Movies) context.lookup("java:global/injection-of-entitymanager/Movies");
Replace Movies with your UserDao. The EJBContainer provides an application context. Out of this context you load beans.

Comment: @Jan you're in an EE container.  you don't even need spring, TBH.  your EJB/CDI beans will automatically be managed, you just inject them appropriately and the container provides them.  as was mentioned above, do not instantiate them with a "new" or they will not be managed.